# Undo Filtering for Noiseless Signal

Tags: filter, transfer-function

Suppose I have a noiseless Signal, which has been filtered with a 2nd order Bessel low pass. I know the filter's transfer function. How can I obtain the unfiltered signal?
Thanks!

Comment: Why is this question different to the one you posted a few minutes ago?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the actual transfer function of the filter then passing the signal through an amplifier with a filter with transfer function equivalent to the original filter in the negative feedback path 'should' return the original signal, subject to any non-idealities encountered along the way.

---

Written late in a too long day.
Hopefully it will seem as correct in the morning as it does now :-).